# 10.2 Tokyo Debugger not working (blue dots not showing)

Tags: c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I've tried at least a week trying to figure out why the debugger for Builder 10.2 Tokyo is not working. It doesn't help that there's a lack of information (even on the Wiki) about this.

We recently migrated code from CB 2010 and the debugger sometimes works. It sometimes works when you clean a package and Build.

I've read somewhere that it could be related to the source files being on a network drive. When building the project, the files state "No Debug Info"

Project options are loaded from optionsets that set C++ Compiler > Debugging > Debug information to true.

Any ideas? Our projects are at a standstill because we can't perform any debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution!

I'm not quite sure what caused it, but renaming/deleting the old Debug output folder and letting it do a full Build got debugging working again!